# jQuery setTimeout for hover links?

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I am having a tabbed script which has switch tabs on hover.
Since links are close together, i want to have a delay before hover function is fired, so content is not switched so fast while user "touches" the rest of the links.

maybe with setTmeout?  Here is my script, how do i do that?

```
$(".HotelPanel_content").hide(); //Hide all content
$("ul.HotelPanelNav li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".HotelPanel_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content


$("ul.HotelPanelNav li").hover(function() {
    $("ul.HotelPanelNav li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".HotelPanel_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("id"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).slideDown("slow"); //Fade in the active content
    return false;
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var thisCache;
var hoverTimeout;
$("ul.HotelPanelNav li").mouseenter(function() {
    thisCache = $(this);
    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $("ul.HotelPanelNav li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        thisCache.addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".HotelPanel_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = thisCache.find("a").attr("id"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).slideDown("slow"); //Fade in the active content
        },300)
    });
$("ul.HotelPanelNav li").mouseleave(function(){
    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout)
})
```

Comment: Yes Litek,

your solution worked best for me.
That was it

Thx for your ideas, all of you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add .delay() to any jquery animation method.  This method takes a time in miliseconds so you could do this on the animation.

```
$(activeTab).delay(5000).slideDown("slow");
```

I believe you could also delay the function

```
$("ul.HotelPanelNav li").delay(5000).hover(function() {
```

**Edit**

You can also use the .timeout function

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    callYourFunction();
}, 1000);
```

**Edit 2**

This work fine for me

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#somelink").hover(function(){
        window.setTimeout(function() {
        //put your code here
        }, 1000);
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="flash">
</div>
<div id="somelink">
    Hello this is a div
</div>
```

Comment: Hi,  thank you, but what i actually need is to delay the function after link is hovered (switch to next content)
Because my problem is that:
1. Links are one below other
Link a
Link b
Link c
2. content panel is below links which has embeeded links ( a seperate navigation)

Problem:
Selecting to see (e.g) link a  the user must navigate to content below, but on the way down, he hovers over Link b +c

so, i need to delay the whole hover action

Comment: In that case you will need to use the setTimeout function.  See this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: hmm, still can't make it work. can you show it on my code above? I need when hover over link, to delay the action "show next content"

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do it this way

```
$("ul.HotelPanelNav li").hover(function() {
   settTimeout('yourfunction($this);', time)
});

function yourfunction(element){
  $("ul.HotelPanelNav li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
  $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
  $(".HotelPanel_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
  var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("id"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
  $(activeTab).slideDown("slow"); //Fade in the active content
  return false;
}
```